# Stretch Text to get it to touch the edges of View

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a view with text inside it. I'd like the text to stretch and touch the edges of the view.

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "lightblue"}}>
   <Text style={{fontSize: 55}}>
     {totalBalance}
   </Text>
</View>
```

[image]

I've tried adding `flex: 1`, `height:'100%'`, `adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}`, and `includeFontPadding:false` (although this seems to be android only, and I'm testing on IOS) to the text style, but none of these things have worked.

If I add `backgroundColor: red` to the text element, the background covers the whole view, but the font doesn't. This makes me think that the font might have some sort of padding?

[image]

Is there any way I can make the `$0` in the image stretch to touch the edges of the blue view?

Comment: Could you post the part of your code responsible for rendering the widget?

Comment: You could use negative margins but I that those margins are set by the Text component or even could be set by he font family itself in which case there is no much you can do